# Emulator for iPhone in windows

Tags: android, iphone, ios, windows, android-emulator

I have app created in eclipse and tested in Android Emulator. I want the same app to be tested in iphone also. By searching, I found there was no way to verify the app in Emulator in Windows. I can do only in MAC.

Is there anyway to test my app in windows in iphone emulator?

Comment: Eh, you're aware that iOS is not android, right? Your question is vague and if you're talking about a native Application you need to write it in Objective C with XCode, only available on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web-based app, I would suggest trying it out in Safari on Windows; I've had good luck in the past with this approach. If the application is Adobe Air based you can expect its operation to be nearly identical to Android; FlashBuilder also provides an emulator for iOS devices built-in.

Comment: can you brief me about safari.

Comment: Install safari for windows from here: http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531 and then access your app (I'm not sure how you have things set up at that point)

Answer (score 0):

I found MobiOne software which is used to test App in iphones and Android phone also. That helps me to solve my issue.